# Ubuntu frontier DSL internet not working?

Tags: internet, ethernet, dsl, router

I recently installed ubuntu 11.10 on an older computer Pentium 4 dual 3.0 chips.

Ubuntu installed and runs great, but cannot get the internet to work. Will not recognize either the ethernet card, or the router. Not sure which.

Any suggestions.?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Regards,

Comment: Additional to blueXrider recomendation, it would be helpful to know if you are trying to connect it wireless or wired.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

As long as your router uses IPv4 or IPv6(99% of routers do), your problem isn't with the router. If you know what kind of network card you have, you can try to get Linux drivers for it by downloading them on a different computer onto a flash drive, then installing on your system. If you can tell me what kind of ethernet card you have(Or even the exact model number of your computer, as long as you didn't change the ethernet card), I can point you to a link to get the right files and give you info on how to install.